# Secure File Transfer alternative

Tags: active-directory, ftp, file-sharing

I am looking into secure file transfer programs.  My company is looking to phase out ftp for sharing files with outside vendors. I need a solution that allows creation of ad-hoc users on the fly. It would be helpful if the solution was Active Directory friendly. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about SFTP?

If you look at [THIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_FTP_server_software) wiki link it lists a number of servers that support both SFTP and AD - including the excellent [CrushFTP](http://www.crushftp.com/) and [zFTP](http://www.zftpserver.com/index.php/base/home/wiki).

Comment: don't forget the free FreeFTPd - http://www.freesshd.com/

Comment: I think you mean FTPS.

Comment: @Jason He cites servers that support both SFTP (SSH+FTP) and FTPS (FTP+TLS/SSL), why would you suppose he meant FTPS instead of what he said?

Comment: @Kromney, maybe I didn't read the article closely enough but the title is: "Comparison of FTP server software"

Answer (score 2):

You can do FTPS (FTP with SSL) to get the security. Why not just add security to the existing solution rather than change the solution? Wouldn't your outside vendors prefer that approach?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

How about [webdav](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/350/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis-7/)? You can set IIS to use integrated auth and assign permissions to a domain local group. You can also secure it via SSL.